# python with scientific notation EXY

Tags: python, scientific-notation

So I am writing  the columns of an array to a file and the file is to be used by a program that is space sensitive, so it has to be exactly the right way like this:

```
*DEFINE_CURVE_TRIM 
$     TCID    TCTYPE      TFLG      TDIR     TCTOL  TOLN/IGB     NSEED 
      1111         1        -1         0     0.001
 7.50000E01 , 0.00000E00
 7.49906E01 , 1.18995E00
 7.49622E01 , 2.37960E00
```

I am working with some floats with alot of decimals, so I am rounding them to have the same number of decimals, but python notation is E+01 and it has to be E01

```
udskrift = open('DEFINE_CURVE_TRIM_FULL','w')
udskrift.write('*DEFINE_CURVE_TRIM\n$     TCID    TCTYPE      TFLG      TDIR     TCTOL  TOLN/IGB     NSEED\n      1111         1        -1         0     0.001\n')
for entry in polar_koordinator:
    udskrift.write(" %.5E , %.5E\n" % (entry[2], entry[3]))
```

output is

```
*DEFINE_CURVE_TRIM
$     TCID    TCTYPE      TFLG      TDIR     TCTOL  TOLN/IGB     NSEED
      1111         1        -1         0     0.001
 8.00976E+01 , 0.00000E+00
 8.01050E+01 , 1.25839E+00
```

So any pointers on how to remove the '+' so it becomes E01? I would hate to have to reopen the file and remove them

Comment: Would you still expect the minus sign for negative powers of ten?  e.g. 1.23456E-13?

Comment: Yes I actually haven't given it much thought, but when looking at the original I can find 2 examples of E-01 so guess LS-dyna can accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way out is to write

```
udskrift.write((" %.5E , %.5E\n" % (entry[2], entry[3])).replace('E+', 'E'))
```

but that does not seem pythonic.

Comment: This would have been my recommendation if the answer to my question above came back a yes.